# How can I setup a P2P webserver chat application through Tor

Tags: website

I'm new to Tor and P2P applications so I'm completely lost with what approach I should go with, if someone could give me some guidance I'd really appreciate it (I know using p2p is not good in Tor because of the resources but I need to it like this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using p2p with Tor is **absolutely normal** ! Just resolve your peers *as an onion addresses*, and it will be just fine! To utilize your application needs - map it's ports in your config and pin them statically in your app's config. That's it!

Comment: Could you point me to a guide to follow or something alike? I've been trying for a whole week to create and connect 2 different hidden services but I'm having trouble finding a good explanation. I've been using Python with Flask and Stem but yeah, having a lot of troubles. I see a lot of examples using sockets but I want to display something on a webserver, on Tor and yeah, I can't really find anything near what I want/need

Comment: Using python and Flask - keep in mind that you need to forward your Flask port for a hidden service **and** declare it's hostname as an onion address. PM me on facebook page from my profile and I will be able to give you more direct answers if you need